# How to create a public database in Android Studio to have connection between different apps?

Tags: java, android

I have an Android app that needs to retrieve info from a server that isn't related to the app.
I'll try to be more clear:
There's a server that is being updated every once in a while, and I need the devices to retrieve data from that server. How can I achieve this?

I thought about SQLite but I don't seem to understand how it will connect to an external database that isn't on the device

Comment: Have you thought about [firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore)?

Comment: @tomerpacific ah thats a good idea thanks